# Faye doesn't send messages in production

Tags: faye

I use faye through the PrivatePub gem to publish messages to my clients. It works fine in development on my machine but on my production server messages never make it to the clients.

I'm pretty sure that faye is setup properly as its requesting faye.js no problem from the server and its not logging any errors in the client. I'm not seeing any errors on the server either so I'm at a loss as to why its not sending messages out to the clients.

Comment: some code would help!